# How do I show a SwiftUI Subview fullscreen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

Take a look at the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I marked the "Top Navigation Bar" red, which I want to remove, as there is an unused top bar...

You have to know that I code using Storyboards, but this specific page is holding a **subview of SwiftUI View**!

*This is the SwiftUI ContentView:*

```
    import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            MasterView()
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {
     var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Geplant")) {
                    Section {
                        NavigationLink(destination: UIKitView()) { Text("Berlin") }

                    }
                
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Wohin gehts?")
    }
}

struct UIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = SwipeViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SwipeViewController {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "swipe") as! SwipeViewController
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SwipeViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

And this is the UIViewController, which is holding the SwiftUI Subview:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class StartViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    
    let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureBackgroundGradient()
        addChild(contentView)
        view.addSubview(contentView.view)
        setupContraints()
    }

    fileprivate func setupContraints(){
        contentView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    private func configureBackgroundGradient() {
      let backgroundGray = UIColor(red: 244 / 255, green: 247 / 255, blue: 250 / 255, alpha: 1)
      let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
      gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, backgroundGray.cgColor]
      gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
      view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0) //Background Color
    }
}
```

Can anyone can help? :))

Thank you! Feel free to ask me for more screenshots or code!

Answer (score 1):

Let us take simple FullScreenModalView struct that can dismiss itself, then presents it from ContentView when another button is pressed:

```
struct FullScreenModalView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss Modal") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for ContentView -

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present!") {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, content: FullScreenModalView.init)
    }
}
```

Happy to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a view in full screen with the SwiftUI view modifiere fullScreenCover. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-full-screen-modal-view-using-fullscreencover

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed. If there is relevant code within the link please post it in the answer. Over time links become inactive making answers obsolete.